# Ruby quickly see what fields are in an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am debugging `google-client-api` output and get a `<Google::APIClient::Result:0x007f61183571b0` object back. How can I see what fields are in that?

Experimentation has shown that there are response and request fields in there but I tried calling `.inspect` on it but it doesn't actually display anything broken out but rather a large chunk of text.

For readability I am doign this in my rails controller

`render json: gaquery.inspect`

Comment: Are you using a gem to do this?  If so it will be in the gem's api doc.

Comment: You mean like pretty-printing a JSON parse?

Comment: Try `(result.methods - Object.public_instance_methods).sort`, where `result` is the variable name of the object in question.

Comment: brilliant! Max Williams, make it an answer and I'll accept it (ps my name is max too :))

Comment: There is no such thing as a "field" in Ruby. Please clarify what exactly you are looking for. If you are talking about what Java calls a "field", then the equivalent in Ruby would be "instance variable", and that is *not* what the answer shows you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(result.methods - Object.public_instance_methods).sort
```

, where `result` is the variable name of the object in question.

Although it would still be better to find the documentation for it and look there.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `pry`, and enter `ls object`.